# ASP.NET - Change profile information in pagemethod?

Tags: asp.net, profile, pagemethods

I can only to get data, but how can I set.

```
        ProfileBase pc = HttpContext.Current.Profile;
        pc.PropertyValues["field"] = false; //error
        pc.Save();
```

'''''''''''''

Ok, I dont have access to HttpContext.Current.Profile.FieldName from webmethod, but i can:

```
projectPage thisPage = new projectPage ();
thisPage.updateProfile(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 HttpContext.Current.Profile.FieldName = "Set your Value";
```

For Details please check this Article [Profiles In ASP.NET 2.0](http://odetocode.com/articles/440.aspx)